# Map keys to commands when a pom.xml is present in the current directory?

Tags: maven, vim

is it possible to map keys in vim only when a pom.xml is present in the current directory?  I know it is possible to map keys when a certain file type is open, but I can't figure out how to map keys based on the presence of a file.

I could like to add some keybindings to vim to aid in development of maven projects.  For example, when I want to browse the sources of dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:unpack-dependencies
  -Dclassifier=sources
  -Dmdep.failOnMissingClassifierArtifact=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like this into your vimrc:

```
function! IfPomXmlExists()
  if file_readable("pom.xml")
    " define your commands here..
    map <buffer> <C-F9> :echo "hello pom!"<CR>
  endif
endfunction

augroup pomxml
  au!
  autocmd BufReadPre * call IfPomXmlExists()
augroup END
```

Answer (score -1):

here you have some examples with [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)
    You can get inspiration there. i.e.  from this:

```
:  autocmd FileAppendPre        *.gz !mv <afile>:r <afile>
```